# UNCODE/espace special characters JSON DATA Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services

We are sending JSON data from UI using Ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
      url: "/RegisterUser", 
      type: "POST",
      Contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json", 
      data: JSON.stringify(formData), 
      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) 
               { 
                  alert(data);
               }



       }); 


@RequestMapping(value="/RegisterUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ServiceResponse registerUser(
        @RequestBody String UserDetails) {

    logger.info("JSON DATA"+UserDetails);
```

}

But, data from webservice coming with special characters, How to handle??

```
%7B%22Test%22%3A%7B%22Test11%22%3A%22Test%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Test11%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22Test%40gmail.com%22%7D%2C%22Details%22%3A%7B%22date_of_brith%22%3A%2205%2F01%2F2015%22%2C%22gender%22%3A%22Male%22%2C%22
```

How to decode/escape data to String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

Try and use:

```
final String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "UTF-8");
```